# How do I remove the 'split lines' error in Bluefish?

Tags: fedora, editors

How can I stop this error from occurring **every time** I start Bluefish editor?

*<sub>Of course, apart from shortening long lines...</sub>*

[image: error]

Bluefish 2.2.4, running on Fedora 19.

**Edit:**

I have done this in settings:

[image: editor]

Which annoyingly, had no effect at all...

Comment: Someone else with the same problem on AU: http://askubuntu.com/questions/377227/how-to-stop-bluefish-from-displaying-file-contains-very-long-lines-split-these. Asked on Nov. 15th 2013, no one's answer that Q either.

Comment: That is why I did not post it there @slm, as they have a rather odd attitude of marking everything as duplicates... Also as it had not been posted on this particular forum.

Comment: That wasn't a negative comment, just creating a linkage.

Comment: I know - that's why I upvoted :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Similar sounding bug?

Not sure if this issue is related or not but if you look at the details of this issue in the Bluefish bugzilla issue tracker. The issue is titled: [Very long lines and cpu usage](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=701628), which doesn't sound related but if you look through the question:

*excerpt*

> I've tested this with bluefish 2.2.2, built against gtk+-2.24.17 and later
>   against gtk+-3.4.4, I got the same behavior.
>
> I do a lot of css editing, and I found some time ago that base64 images where a
>   problem. And the bigger they were, the bigger the problem was as well.
>
> base64 images can result in very long lines, even small images, because bitmap
>   info has to be stored using a subset of ascii (or whatever). So it's not
>   strange that I end with lines with +10,000 columns, sometimes much longer.
>
> When I scroll down such a file, the very moment the offending line is about to
>   appear the editor freezes, and I can see gkrellm becoming mad about cpu usage.
>   I can open the same file in nano and scroll as I wish without even noticing a
>   cpu peak.
>
> When a CSS file is full of this stuff I just close bluefish and use whatever is
>   at hand instead.

One of the developers then made this comment:

> thanks for reporting, unfortunately this is a known bug in the gtk textview
>   widget.
>
> there is a bugreport for gtk somewhere in bugzilla, but it hasn't been fixed
>   for years. I'm surprised that the windows build doesn't have this problem, it
>   also uses gtk....

I realize the error you're seeing sounds different but these 2 issues seem linked to me. I  would suggest filing this as a bug and seeing what the developers

#### Opened issue regarding this

To try and help expedite this issue for you and the other OP on AU I filed this as a bug in Bugzilla for the Bluefish project.

- [Bug 720494 - Disable message complaining about file containing very long lines?](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=720494)

Feel free to comment on that, hopefully we'll hear something soon regarding this issue.

Comment: I myself have had no problem with long lines and CPU usage, but I will take a look at the Bug report.

Comment: Also, forgot to mention, I mainly design web apps with base64 encoded images - hence VERY long lines...

Comment: Apparently, the thing should be fixed in the 2.2.5 release of Bluefish - https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=720494#c3